# Listing all varchars that contain exactly same letters or numbers

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have a coloumn that has a hashed string, for example something like this:

`D8D44CFADD8BB8F0F4D98FD80.0`

I want to view all columns that share the same hashed string.

Okay, maybe I should go straight forward.

This is a special string that hashes special data from a user's computer and puts them in to their userdata. What I heard is that this string can sometimes be inefficient and does not become unique but it is supposed to be. I want to see how efficient it is and what is the possibility for two users to have the same hashed string at once.

So in other words I want to see a list of the ones that have the same hashed string in their data, but note that I do not want it for a specific string (D8D44CFADD8DDE8F0F4D98FD80.0.1) for what I would use search and check whoever has the same combination. What I want to see is who has the same string with who.

How can I get this done in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When an answer helps you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark. That way we can develop a good archive of questions and useful answers.

Comment: You should also update your profile - I know no devs who do not use SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT hashed_string_field, COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY hashed_string_field
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```